# Not able to get SAMSUNG S4 native browser history

Tags: android, android-service, android-browser

I am accessing the browser history from device native browser. I use following code -

```
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
            new String[] { Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL }, null, null,
            BookmarkColumns.DATE + " DESC");
```

It works fine in all devices, but in SAMSUNG S4 Cursor returns null.
I find that in devices where i get proper response, Browser package is 'com.android.browser' but in S4 device it is 'com.sec.android.app.sbrowser'. Is that the issue? But this is native browser in Samsung S4.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hm i'm trying to get browser histry from all browsers,too. But i think READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS only fetchs the history fro chrome. Samsung has its own browser, so it does not show up. If you start chrome on your s4, it should be listed

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

`Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.sec.android.app.sbrowser.browser/history");` instead of `Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI`.