# how to get History from sbrowser?

Tags: android

I want to get History of sbrowser? I try used  "com.sec.android.app.sbrowser.browser/history" but it is not working.

```
final Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.sec.android.app.sbrowser.browser/history");
final Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
if (c!=null && c.moveToFirst()) {
  do {
    System.out.println(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("URL")));
  } while(c.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: `it is not working` how exactly? Crashing? not returning results?

Comment: Cursor c is always null. Can not get url parameter.

Comment: then `content://com.sec.android.app.sbrowser.browser/history"` may be incorrect. Where did you get it?

Comment: I get it from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370108/not-able-to-get-samsung-s4-native-browser-history

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I found that the correct URI is

```
content://com.sec.android.app.sbrowser.browser/bookmarks
```

**Check out this post** [Android Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI does not work on all devices. How to find out the correct uri for a given device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28040445/android-browser-bookmarks-uri-does-not-work-on-all-devices-how-to-find-out-the/28403816#28403816)

Answer (score 0):

The other way to get the history

```
Cursor mycur = managedQuery(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION, null, 
null, null);
    int count = mycur.getCount();
    mycur.moveToFirst();
    if(mycur.moveToFirst() && count>0)
    {
        while(count>0)
        {
            Log.e("title",mycur.getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_URL_INDEX));
            mycur.moveToNext();
        }
    }
```

You can check below also some other answers

[Get browser history and search result in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626084/get-browser-history-and-search-result-in-android)